# Accept connections only by short link

Tags: php, html

I want to make my web site so that it can only be accessed from visitors that accessed via a short link, and block them when they access my web by entering the address.
how can i do it on .htaccess?

Comment: So, do you want codez?

Comment: Good luck with it

Comment: yes, i want the codes

Answer (score 0):

In php you can check for the previous URL by using $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].

So you can compare the previous url with $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] to verify the visit.

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == 'your-short-url') {
//redirect to home page 
} else { 
//display page not found; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Store shortlink addresses in the DB and then validate them on server site. The second approach is to check if the domain is comming from your shortlink provider, f.i. bit.ly

```
$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST] == 'bit.ly';
```

To check current address in php:

```
$actual_link = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
```

current browser URL using JavaScript:

```
window.location.href
```

This will return you the string with URL you currently see in your browser.
If you choose DB use approach compare each element in database with your current url and display website only if they are matching, coming from the same domain or any condition you want.